# Stripping strings from a MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, replace

Is it possible to run some SQL to change the contents of a field?

My field looks like this

```
..//uploaded_images/1284058574.jpg
```

and I want it to simply be

```
1284058574.jpg
```

all the records that I wish to change will start with

```
..//uploaded_images/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's already in the database you could do a find and replace?

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, '..//uploaded_images/', '(REPLACE TEXT LEAVE EMPTY)');
```

you may or may not have to character escape the slashes, I'm not sure on that one